# Проверка близости пользователя к точке на карте

Tags: python, геолокация, gps

Идея такая - есть точки на карте. При приближении на определенный радиус к точке пользователь оповещается о ее близости. Приложение получает координаты в виде списка (долгота, широта). Как построить архитектуру такого приложения? В моем видении, есть база данных с координатами точек. То есть сначала приложение получает координаты от юзера, и затем последовательно проверяет каждую точку из базы данных на близость? Но тогда выходит слишком ресурсозатратно. В общем, буду благодарен любому совету - опыта работы с геоданными нет.

Answer (score 0):

А зачем "ресурсозатратно" проверять все подряд точки из базы?   Если бы меня припекла необходимость сохранения ресурсов, я бы сначала искал несколько точек, ближайших по одной координате (ну, или те, которые не далее чем.... по этой координате), потом - по второй, потом делал бы пересечение полученных множеств точек. Если информация храниться в базе данных -  то не особо затратно получиться. Если в файлах -  можно предварительно точки сортировать.